# Google Map- Polygons

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api, asp.net

I construct three polygons in the google map using the help polygons in google Map API for developers site. They are look like one polygon inside an another polygon .When my page is loaded all three polygon are loaded.How can i get the inner polygon when the outer polygon is zoomed or clicked in google map?[image: Image:polygon inside another polygon]